# How use regexp match all repeat substring in javascript?

Tags: javascript, regex

How use regexp match all repeat substring in javascript?

For example:
Get `[ "cd","cd","cdcd","cdcdcd", "cdcdcdcd" ]` by "abccdddcdcdcdcd123"

`+` is not working:

```
"abccdddcdcdcdcd123".match(/(cd)+/g)
Array [ "cd", "cdcdcdcd" ]
```

Comment: You are asking for overlapping regex.

Comment: Note that using _match_ in JS has trouble with getting captures within lookahead assertions. Use the re _exec_ method instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done with positive look aheads `?=`. This type of matching doesnt move the cursor forward so you can match the same content multiple times.

```js
var re = /cd(?=((cd)*))/g;
var str = "abccdddcdcdcdcd123"; 
var m;
while (m = re.exec(str)) {
  console.log(m[0]+m[1]);
}
```

Capture group 0 gets the first `cd`, then a positive lookahead captures all subsequent `cd` characters. You can combine the two to get the desired result.

---

See https://www.regular-expressions.info/refadv.html

> Matches at a position where the pattern inside the lookahead can be matched. Matches only the position. It does not consume any characters or expand the match. In a pattern like one(?=two)three, both two and three have to match at the position where the match of one ends.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you could also do it like this.

Put the capture group inside a lookahead assertion.
Most engines bump the current regex position if it didn't change since
last match. Not JS though, you have to do it manually via incrementing `lastIndex`.

Readable regex

```
 (?=
      (                             # (1 start)
           (?: cd )+
      )                             # (1 end)
 )
```

```js
var re = /(?=((?:cd)+))/g;
var str = "abccdddcdcdcdcd123"; 
var m;
while (m = re.exec(str)) {
  console.log( m[1] );
  ++re.lastIndex;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the common solution to an overlapping match problem like this should be as following:

```
/(?=((cd)+))cd
```

Match the inner pattern in group one or more times in a lookahead whilst moving the carret two characters at a time ahead. (We could also move by two dots `..`).

Code sample:

```js
var re = /(?=((cd)+))cd/g;
var str = "abccdddcdcdcdcd123";
var m; //var arr = new Array();
while (m = re.exec(str)) {
  //arr.push(m[1]);
  console.log(m[1]);
}
```

We get the result from group 1 via `m[1]`.
Use `.push(m[1]);` to add it to an array.